# python backslash regex fun

Tags: python, regex

```
unc = r'\\foo\bar'
string1 = r'\\foo\bar'
string2 = r'\\\\foo\\bar'

if unc == string1:
    print "I wish to make a complaint"

if re.match(string1, unc):
    print "Ello miss"

if re.match(string2, unc):
    print "Sorry I have a cold"
```

Output is:

```
I wish to make a complaint
Sorry I have a cold
```

Seems the re.match operation re-escapes the literal string and so "Ello miss" never happens.

Can anyone explain why I have to re-escape the backslash where setting the string as a literal in the first place?

I want to keep a list of UNC paths in a configuration file and I'd prefer not to have to escape strings in that. While the comparator works, it would be useful to have a regex option available.

Comment: Your `.format()` calls are redundant.. `string1` and `string2` are *already* strings.

Comment: over `r'my_regex_wild_pattern'` I even prefer `"""my_regex_gentle_pattern"""` : the only bad surprise I can have is on the last character.

Comment: @StephaneRolland: The point is that there are escape sequences both for specifying python string literals *and* for regular expressions. By using `r''` raw string literals you disable the Python escape sequences so you can focus on the regular expression meta characters instead.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - yes you're right, I was trimming back some code for this example and overlooked the redundancy. I've edited my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `\` character is a special character in regular expressions, and must be escaped to be taken literally. So, to match the string `\\foo\bar`, you need the regex `\\\\foo\\bar`, as you discovered. You can use the function `re.escape` to create such a regex for you, for inclusion in larger expressions.

```
>>> re.escape(r'\\foo\bar')
'\\\\\\\\foo\\\\bar'           # ouch
```

Comment: @jayuu That's equivalent to `unc.startswith(string1)`. The intended usage of `re.escape` is inserting regular expressions that match a constant string into a larger expression, as in `my_re = '^From:.*%s' % re.match(name)`.

Comment: OK - Did you mean re.escape(name) instead of re.match(name)?

Comment: No worries - got me to think! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In regular expression patterns, a backslash has meaning *too*, and needs to be explicitly escaped.

As such, `\\` means: match one literal `\` character.

If you want to pass literal text to `re.match()`, you need to first escape any possible meta characters using [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Martijn which is appreciated. I accepted the first answer as it was the first reply, and also included some useful contextual information about using escape within a larger regular expression.